# Append Text to $post->post_excerpt

Tags: posts, excerpt

I'm trying to add some text after a product description in WooCommerce which uses the `$post->post_excerpt`.  Currently I'm using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'd4tw_show_dimensions', 20 );
function d4tw_show_dimensions() {
    global $product;
    $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();

    if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
        echo '<span class="dimensions"> Length: ' . $dimensions . '</span>';
    }
}
```

This gets the dimensions to show up after the product summary but it's on it's own line.  How can I append the dimensions within the same paragraph to the post_excerpt?

Comment: This is most probably a CSS question and off topic for that site. Nevertheless: Have a look at the class that the excerpt is using. Possibily it´s set to `display:block;` which causes your appendix to start on a new line. Change it to `inline-block` or even `inline` to have it fixed.

Comment: Interesting...I'm still learning WordPress but know css pretty well and I just never thought of that solution.  Excellent!

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if was helpful

Answer (score 1):

you may get the `excerpt` using:

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
```

and append or prepend it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just setting the paragraph to display:inline-block which allowed the product dimensions to flow up onto that line.